# How can I solve this in Django = UnboundLocalError at / local variable 'form' referenced before assignment

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-queryset

How can I solve this in Django?

> UnboundLocalError at / local variable 'form' referenced before assignment.

```
def home(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        form = MeepForm(request.POST or None)
        if request.method == "POST":
            if form.is_valid():
                meep = form.save(commit=False)
                meep.user = request.user
                meep.save()
                messages.success(request,('Meep has been posted'))
                return redirect('home')
        meeps = Meep.objects.all().order_by("-created_at")
        return render(request, 'home/home.html', {'meeps':meeps,'form':form})
    else:
        meeps = Meep.objects.all().order_by("-created_at")
        return render(request, 'home/home.html', {'meeps':meeps,'form':form})
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use logic that is written similar to Django MVP views - you can just initialize the form before and then override it when it's needed with POST data.

```py
def home(request):
    form = MeepForm()
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = MeepForm(request.POST or None)
            if form.is_valid():
                meep = form.save(commit=False)
                meep.user = request.user
                meep.save()
                messages.success(request, 'Meep has been posted')
                return redirect('home')
    meeps = Meep.objects.all().order_by("-created_at")
    return render(request, 'home/home.html', {'meeps': meeps,'form': form})
```

Answer (score 1):

The error is because of the `form` variable that is being referenced before it is assigned a value. In the case where the user is not authenticated, the `form` variable is not defined, and so you get the `UnboundLocalError`, try this:

```py
def home(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = MeepForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                meep = form.save(commit=False)
                meep.user = request.user
                meep.save()
                messages.success(request, 'Meep has been posted')
                return redirect('home')
            else:
                return redirect("some_error_page")
    form = MeepForm()
    meeps = Meep.objects.all().order_by("-created_at")
    return render(request, 'home/home.html', {'meeps': meeps,'form': form})
```

Answer (score 0):

If your code goes into `else`, then you wouldn't have initialized a `form` object and hence the error.

```
else:
    meeps = Meep.objects.all().order_by("-created_at")
    return render(request, 'home/home.html', {'meeps':meeps,'form':form})
```

Here u wouldn't be having `form`. So initialize it here - inside `else` or have some value before `if`.